# Skype Video not working with Windows Phone 10

Tags: windows-10-mobile, skype

My Skype on my Windows Phone 10 used to work fine up until suddenly, for some reason, I can see the person I am calling but they can't see me. They can hear me but not see me. I can see my video feed just fine but the other person can't. While I can see them just fine. And I can assure that my internet connection is pretty good.

I am on Windows phone build 10.0.14393.693
Phone model: BLU Win HD LTE
Skype Version: Skype Preview 11.11.110.0

And I did try reinstalling.

Comment: Does the front-facing camera work in other apps? For instance, the Camera app. Does Skype Preview have permission to use the camera? You can check in Settings -> Privacy -> Camera.

Comment: @Indrek I did check both. The front camera is working just fine and Skype has all the permissions. This is apparently a bug with the app itself because I browsed over the skype forums and a lot of people have been facing such problems

Comment: Same issue, on lumia 1520, for vertical orientation and 90deg right-horizontal orientation, BUT rotate the phone to 90deg Left-Horizontal orientation and works AOK... tried uninstalling, rebooting, resetting permissions, noting works... camera is however AOK with all other apps, camera is fine with skype to leave a video message in vertical orientation, but for a live skype video call SKYPE stops transmitting video if rotated to vertical orientation. Appears to be working from my side, but there is no video being transferred out by the Application to any other user until it is rotated back to